# Git undo local branch delete

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I just deleted the wrong branch with some experimental changes I need with `git branch -D branchName`.

How do I recover the branch?

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only lame-o who did this (and forgot to regularly push to remote a copy)

Comment: This is, hands down, the most important SO question I have ever looked for

Answer (score 1040, accepted):

You can use [git reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to find the SHA1 of the last commit of the branch. From that point, you can recreate a branch using

```
git branch branchName <sha1>
```

**Edit:** As @seagullJS says, the `branch -D` command tells you the sha1, so if you haven't closed the terminal yet it becomes real easy. For example this deletes and then immediately restores a branch named `master2`:

```
user@MY-PC /C/MyRepo (master)
$ git branch -D master2
Deleted branch master2 (was 130d7ba).    <-- This is the SHA1 we need to restore it!

user@MY-PC /C/MyRepo (master)
$ git branch master2 130d7ba
```

Comment: Git tells you what the SHA1 was when the branch is deleted, so if you just delete it it might just be a few lines up in the command line.

Comment: if this branch exists on the server, alternatively, you can use `git branch branchName origin/branchName`

Comment: in addition i ended up using git cherry-pick <sha1> to move the commit to branch

Comment: For those who delete on IntelliJ GUI, go to the Git tool (`⌘`+`9`)> [Console tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html) and search for `branch -D`

Comment: In GitKraken I went to [Activity Logs](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/activity-logs) and copied the `${sha}` from a line that looked like `Delete ref refs/heads/my-branch at ${sha}`

Answer (score 115):

If you know the last SHA1 of the branch, you can try

```
git branch branchName <SHA1>
```

You can find the SHA1 using `git reflog`, described in the solution --defect link--.

Comment: Thank you so much, I deleted my branch accidentally and it existed locally only (which never happens). You saved me 2 days of my work, thank you again

Answer (score 80):

If you just deleted the branch, you will see something like this in your terminal:

```
Deleted branch branch_name(was e562d13)
```

> - where e562d13 is a unique ID (a.k.a. the "SHA" or "hash"), with this you can restore the deleted branch.

To restore the branch, use:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> <sha>
```

**for example**:

```
git checkout -b branch_name e562d13
```

Answer (score 62):

Follow these Steps:

1: Enter:

```
git reflog show
```

This will display all the Commit history, you need to select the sha-1 that has the last commit that you want to get back

2: create a branch name with the *Sha-1 ID* you selected eg: 8c87714

```
git branch your-branch-name 8c87714
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. My 2 months of work was lost. This solution helped recover those files.

Comment: hahahhaha. it was my 10 mins work and I thought I am in trouble

Answer (score 45):

If you haven't push the deletion yet, you can simply do :

```
$ git checkout deletedBranchName
```

Comment: This answer makes Git Extensions shut up about "the branch you are trying to push seems to be a new branch for this remote." Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

First: back up your entire directory, including the .git directory.

Second: You can use `git fsck --lost-found` to obtain the ID of the lost commits.

Third: rebase or merge onto the lost commit.

Fourth: Always think twice before using -D or --force with git :)

You could also [read this good discussion](http://programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/) of how to recover from this kind of error.

EDIT: By the way, don't run `git gc` (or allow it to run by itself - i.e. don't run `git fetch` or anything similar) or you may lose your commits for ever.

Comment: yeah, that is why we use git, to avoid having to carry all that around. Every action you have committed is still available to you.

Comment: This works great! I was also able to visualize lost commits in a tree: `git fsck --lost-found | awk '/commit/{print $3}' | xargs gitk &`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **IntelliJ IDEA**, in `Event Log` you'll see something like that:

[image]

And may simply restore your **branch**.

Answer (score 7):

If you deleted a branch via `Source Tree`, you could easily find the SHA1 of the deleted branch by going to `View -> Show Command History`.

It should have the next format:

```
Deleting branch ...
...
Deleted branch %NAME% (was %SHA1%)
...
```

Then just follow the original answer.

`git branch branchName <sha1>`

Answer (score 6):

First of all, don't get panic. You are in the right place.
Go on champ, we all make mistakes! That's how we learn!
I wish you health, happiness and success!

Oh for the answer! I think you already figured out!

If not! here is the answer.

```
use git reflog
git checkout branch branch_name commitsha
```

> For more clarification, in the second command branch_name is the name you want to give your branch. commitsha is sha number you want to check out. which you will get from git reflog command.

Once again Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, this worked.

> git branch new_branch_name `sha1`
>
> git checkout new_branch_name

//can see my old checked in files in my old branch

Comment: This is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/217657), please upvote useful answers instead of reposting them.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found
git show d6e883ff45be514397dcb641c5a914f40b938c86
git branch helpme 15e521b0f716269718bb4e4edc81442a6c11c139
```

Answer (score 2):

if you deleted a branch using GUI of a Jetbrains IDE(Goland, phpstorm etc)

go to

`git windows(left-down corner of IDE)` -> `console tab` -> now you can see log of executed commands by IDE and find the branch name and SHA1 from this log