# delete branch and messed up backup..need to recover or jump off bridge

Tags: github, fork, recover

ok so boss told me there were conflicts in my branch.. needed to save off local, delete branch and make new and re-apply changes.
So I was working on multi-projects and saved off wrong code and deleted branch.. duh..
so there is a copy in origin thats like 2 weeks old.. doesnt have latest changes to it..
so if I do the repo-> show show lost commits.. I do see my last commit in there that I think should have my changes in it.. and yes I didnt do a push after I committed..

so I have lots of options when I right click (using FORK).. not sure which is correct to do.. I just want to see what changes I have and if I have to manually copy them over I will.. if I can get them to post to a new branch great... anything... cherry pick seemed correct.. but it wanted to put to some branch that doesnt exist.. not sure if it was creating one or what..

so just looking for some help in recovering my code as best I can..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git undo local branch delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025916/git-undo-local-branch-delete)

Comment: I ended up manually copying the code from the file tree in Fork. I didnt need to try that suggestion, but looks like that would have worked and I thought I marked it as the answer to this.